# Custom url scheme does not start my app

Tags: url, android-intent, android-activity, browser, url-scheme

I know its a repost but none of the answers that I found on other posts did not work for me, and I do not get why.

This is my permisions:

```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.LOCATION_HARDWARE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_GPS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="nl.hgrams.passenger.C2D_MESSAGE" />
```

And this is my main activity:

```
  <activity
        android:name=".activities.PSTimelineActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:label="@string/passenger_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <data android:scheme="psngr://" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Now when I enter the site: psngr.co/applauncher, this page redirects to a page "psnr://" which shows a "Website not available". Shouldn't this url start my app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of :

```
<data android:scheme="psngr://" />
```

I used just:

```
<data android:scheme="psngr" />
```

Now it works, honest mistake.